# Angular Slide Toggle is always enabled with formControlName attribute

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-formbuilder

I am trying to use mat slide toggle compoment from Angular Material but, when I try to initialize the slider with a default value with the [checked] attribute, no matter what is in this field the slider is always checked.

```
<mat-slide-toggle color="primary" [checked]="false" formControlName="{{input.id}}"></mat-slide-toggle>
```

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance,

Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize on the form during initialization or go for `patchValue` instead of using `checked`.

ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

/**
 * @title Basic slide-toggles
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'slide-toggle-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'slide-toggle-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['slide-toggle-overview-example.css'],
})
export class SlideToggleOverviewExample {
  isChecked = true;
  formGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.formGroup = formBuilder.group({
      enableWifi: [true], // <- initialized here
      acceptTerms: [false, Validators.requiredTrue],
    });
    // alternative way -> patchValue ; after the form is initialized and you want to set the values of the slider, you can use patchvalue like so
    this.formGroup.patchValue({enableWifi: true,acceptTerms: false});
  }

  onFormSubmit(formValue: any) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(formValue, null, 2));
  }
}
```

html

```
<form class="example-form" [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit(formGroup.value)" ngNativeValidate>

  <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="enableWifi">Enable Wifi</mat-slide-toggle>
  <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="acceptTerms">Accept Terms of Service</mat-slide-toggle>

  <p>Form Group Status: {{ formGroup.status}}</p>

  <button mat-rasied-button type="submit">Save Settings</button>
</form>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-slide-toggle-example-mgnli8)

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that I was reading the `formControl` value from local storage, so, I was reading `'false'` (a string), which was interpreted as `true`.

Solved the issue by wrapping the local storage variable in a `JSON.parse(...)` to get the clean Boolean value.